# Sencha application to native Android application

Tags: android, extjs

I want to deploy the sencha touch application to native Android (apk) but when I follow the guideline and run the last instruction i.e.

```
sencha package run android.json
```

Here is the my "android.json" file

```
{
/**
 * @cfg {String} applicationName
 * @required
 * This is the name of your application, which is displayed on the device when the app is installed. On IOS, this should match
 * the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
 */
"applicationName":"My Application",

/**
 * @cfg {String} applicationId
 * This is the name namespace for your application. On IOS, this should match the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
 */
"applicationId":"com.mycompany.myAppID",

/**
 * @cfg {String} bundleSeedId
 * A ten character string which stands before aplication ID in Apple Provisioning Portal
 */
"bundleSeedId":"KPXFEPZ6EF",

/**
 * @cfg {String} versionString
 * @required
 * This is the version of your application.
 */
"versionString":"1.0",

/**
 * @cfg {String} iconName
 * This is file name of your icon. This should be in the same directory of this configuration file.
 *
 * For iOS, please refer to their documentation about icon sizes:
 * https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html
 *
 * For Android, please refer to the Google Launcher icons guide:
 * http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html
 */
"iconName":"icon.png",

/**
 * @cfg {String} inputPath
 * @required
 * This is location of your Sencha Touch 2 application, relative to this configuration file.
 */
"inputPath":"./",

/**
 * @cfg {String} outputPath
 * @required
 * This is where the built application file with be saved.
 */
"outputPath":"../../st2/",

/**
 * @cfg {String} configuration
 * @required
 * This is configuration for your application. `Debug` should always be used unless you are submitting your app to an online
 * store - in which case `Release` should be specified.
 */
"configuration":"Debug",

/**
 * @cfg {String} platform
 * @required
 * This is the platform where you will be running your application. Available options are:
 *  - iOSSimulator
 *  - iOS
 *  - Android
 *  - AndroidEmulator
 */
"platform":"iOSSimulator",

/**
 * @cfg {String} deviceType
 * @required
 * This is device type that your application will be running on.
 *
 * If you are developing for Android, this is not necessary.
 *
 * Available options are:
 *  - iPhone
 *  - iPad
 *  - Universal
 */
"deviceType":"Universal",

/**
 * @cfg {String} certificatePath
 * This is the location of your certificate.
 * This is required when you are developing for Android or you are developing on Windows.
 */
"certificatePath":"/path/to/certificate.file",

/**
 * @cfg {String} certificateAlias
 * This is the name of your certificate.
 *
 * IF you do not specify this on OSX, we will try and automatically find the certificate for you using the applicationId.
 *
 * This can be just a simple matcher. For example, if your certificate name is "iPhone Developer: Robert Dougan (ABCDEFGHIJ)", you
 * can just put "iPhone Developer".
 *
 * When using a certificatePath on Windows, you do not need to specify this.
 */
"certificateAlias":"",
/**
 * @cfg {String} sdkPath
 * This is the path to the Android SDK, if you are developing an Android application.
 */
"sdkPath":"/path/to/android-sdk",

/**
/**
 * @cfg {String} androidAPILevel
 * This is android API level, the version of Android SDK to use, you can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html.
 * Be sure to install corresponding platform API in android SDK manager (android_sdk/tools/android)
 */
"androidAPILevel":"7",

/**
 * @cfg {Array[String]} orientations
 * @required
 * This is orientations that this application can run.
 */
"orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",
    "portraitUpsideDown"
]
}
```

It creates an My Application.app file not the app file.
How to create the apk file using sencha sdk tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check out the [Native Packaging Guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android) for Android?

You will need to read that guide, and then in your json file edit the paths to reflect your paths, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Inorder to create apk file you need to use

```
stbuild package android.json
```

you'll also need sencha cmd v3.0 for the same

http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download